# Como Esconder/Mostrar div com base em um radio botton e colocar todo o script no html

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estava buscando essa informação aqui no stack overflow e encontrei uma pergunta que me ajudou e funcionou, mas não consigo colocar no html da minha página, sem a necessidade de um arquivo script.js.

```
$('input[name="FlgPontua"]').change(function () {
if ($('input[name="FlgPontua"]:checked').val() === "Sim") {
    $('.camposExtras').show();
} else {
    $('.camposExtras').hide();
}
```

});

Essa parte precisa ser integrada ao html também.

```
$('input[name="FlgPontua"]').change(function () {
if ($('input[name="FlgPontua"]:checked').val() === "Sim") {
    $('.camposExtras').show();
} else {
    $('.camposExtras').hide();
}
```

});

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: *"mas não consigo colocar no html da minha página, sem a necessidade de um arquivo script.js."* procure na internet sobre a tag `<script>`

Answer (score -2):

Começa por criar uma tag script no html onde vai existir toda a lógica seguinte:

- buscar o radio button através da chamada `document.getElementById(id do radio button no html)`
- determinar se a opção 'Nao' está selecionada, `if ($('input[name="FlgPontua"]:checked').val() === "Sim")`
- se a opção escolhida for para esconder, muda-se a visibility para 'hidden', i.e. `document.getElementById(id da div).style.visibility = 'hidden'`; caso contrário se for para mostrar, fica 'visible'.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).